# How do I count the number of lines that are full-line comments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a file as input and prints the number of lines that are full-line comments (i.e. the line begins with #followed by some comments).

For example a file that contains say the following lines should print the result 2:

```
abc
#some random comment
cde
fgh
#another random comment
```

So far I tried along the lines of but just not picking up the hash symbol:

```
infile = open("code.py", "r")
line = infile.readline()

def countHashedLines(filename) :

     while line != "" :
           hashes = '#'
           value = line
           print(value) #here you will get all
           #if(value == hashes):  tried this but just wasn't working
           #      print("hi")
           for line in value:
           line = line.split('#', 1)[1]
           line = line.rstrip()
           print(value)
           line = infile.readline()
   return()
```

Thanks in advance,
Jemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-worded a few statements for ease of use (subjective) but this will give you the desired output.

```
def countHashedLines(lines):
    tally = 0
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('#'): tally += 1
    return tally

infile = open('code.py', 'r')
all_lines = infile.readlines()

num_hash_nums = countHashedLines(all_lines) # <- 2

infile.close()
```

...or if you want a compact and clean version of the function...

```
def countHashedLines(lines):
    return len([line for line in lines if line.startswith('#')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the file through standard input

```
import sys

count = 0 

for line in sys.stdin: """ Note: you could also open the file and iterate through it"""
    if line[0] == '#': """ Every time a line begins with # """
        count += 1 """ Increment """


print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that uses regular expressions and will detect comments that have white space in front.

```
import re

def countFullLineComments(infile) :
    count = 0
    p = re.compile(r"^\s*#.*$")
    for line in infile.readlines():
        m = p.match(line)
        if m:
            count += 1
            print(m.group(0))
    return count

infile = open("code.py", "r")
print(countFullLineComments(infile))
```